# Unable to return Array list added into retrofit enqueue method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I try to add arrays into a an array inside retrofit enqueue method. but it doesn't return array. i have codes like below. i don't know what mistake i made.

```
private fun getAllAudio():ArrayList<Music>{
    val templList = ArrayList<Music>()
    val service = SongFactory.makeSongLists()
    val response = service.getAllSongs()
    response.enqueue(object :Callback<ArrayList<Music>>{
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ArrayList<Music>>,
            response: Response<ArrayList<Music>>
        ) {
            response.body()?.let {
                for (items in it){
                    var music = Music(items.album,items.artist,items.duration,items.id,items.path,items.songuri,items.title)
                    templList.add(music)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Music>>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Error ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })
    Log.d("get",templList.toString())
    return templList
}
```

i tried log my result it displayed []

Answer (score 0):

u have to return `templList` inside onResponse() function, because retrofit takes some milliseconds time, but here u r returning empty list without getting response.

Comment: i tried to return inside retrofit response. it displays type mismatch error. i tried like this 'for (items in it){
                        var music = Music(items.album,items.artist,items.duration,items.id,items.path,items.songuri,items.title)
                        templList.add(music)
                        return templList
//                        Log.d("gg",templList.toString())

                    }'

Comment: May be u have missing some headers in ur API call Request like 

X-Authorization: "djkfdsjkfjk"
 I  X-Authorization-user: username
 I  client_id: 10002
 I  Content-Type: application/json